# Why do we use provider (context, theme provider, provider in redux ie...)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm new to Redux and so curious about wrapper components such as:
`Provider`, `ThemeProvider`, `contextProvider` etc.
in the documentation written as necessary for accessing the store for other nested component.
I want to understand under the hood what the wrapper component does...

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './App'
import store from './store'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  // Render a `<Provider>` around the entire `<App>`,
  // and pass the Redux store to as a prop
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `provider` giving you `context` across the app, it's [using react context internally](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.tsx) that create a closure, and then you can access with the hooks in the app such as `useSelector` and `useDispatch` or with the [connect API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).

You can read more in the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider).